# Multiprocessing Pool.map() freezes on Linux

Tags: python, linux, machine-learning, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing for parallelization of my code, specifically I am using pool.map().When I run my script on my PC it works perfectly, but when I run it on linux server it fails, it just freezes. Does somebody know reason for this?

Here is part of code that is parallelized:

```
with mp.Pool(2) as my_pool: 
   memory= my_pool.map(make_data,data_input)
```

make_data is function that takes solid amount of time, specified by some parameters to run, and data_input are arguments for every function call. Is there any difference with Linux and Windows. Linux manages just to create two processes(same number as workers specified in creating pool), and then freezes.

Comment: Linux and Windows use a different method for starting processes (`fork` instead of `spawn`). You need to follow the "Explicitly pass resources to child processes" and "Safe importing of main module" from the docs to make things portable.